# Replace the start of line in a file quickly

Tags: c#, regex, file-io

I have an initial file containing lines such as:

```
34    964:0.049759 1123:0.0031 2507:0.015979 
32,48 524:0.061167 833:0.030133 1123:0.002549
34,52 534:0.07349 698:0.141667 1123:0.004403 
106   389:0.013396 417:0.016276 534:0.023859
```

The first part of a line is the class number. A line can have several classes.

For each class, I create a new file.

For instance for class 34 the resulting file will be :

```
+1 964:0.049759 1123:0.0031 2507:0.015979 
-1 524:0.061167 833:0.030133 1123:0.002549
+1 534:0.07349 698:0.141667 1123:0.004403 
-1 389:0.013396 417:0.016276 534:0.023859
```

For class 106 the resulting file will be :

```
-1 964:0.049759 1123:0.0031 2507:0.015979 
-1 524:0.061167 833:0.030133 1123:0.002549
-1 534:0.07349 698:0.141667 1123:0.004403 
+1 389:0.013396 417:0.016276 534:0.023859
```

The problem is I have 13 files to write for 200 class. 
I already ran a less optimized version of my code and it took several hours. 
With my code below it takes 1 hour to generate the 2600 files.

**Is there a way to perform such a replacement in a faster way? Are regex a viable option?**

Below is my implementation (works on LINQPAD with [this data file](https://mega.co.nz/#!tRV10S4J!aQtptKTdzC_BKh4NHwiQqaJc7yGv9niQgPyBBgTRoNU))

```
static void Main()
{
    const string filePath = @"C:\data.txt";
    const string generatedFilesFolderPath = @"C:\";
    const string fileName = "data";

    using (new TimeIt("Whole process"))
    {
        var fileLines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2)).ToList();
        var classValues = GetClassValues();
        foreach (var classValue in classValues)
        {
            var directoryPath = Path.Combine(generatedFilesFolderPath, classValue);

            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);

            var classFilePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);

            using (var file = new StreamWriter(classFilePath))
            {
                foreach (var line in fileLines)
                {
                    var lineFirstPart = line.First();
                    string newFirstPart = "-1";

                    var hashset = new HashSet<string>(lineFirstPart.Split(','));
                    if (hashset.Contains(classValue))
                    {
                        newFirstPart = "+1";
                    }

                    file.WriteLine("{0} {1}", newFirstPart, line.Last());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.Read();
}

public static List<string> GetClassValues()
{
    // In real life there is 200 class values.
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList(); 
}

public class TimeIt : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly Stopwatch _watch;
    public TimeIt(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} took {1}", _name, _watch.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Whole process took 00:00:00.1175102
```

EDIT: I also ran a profiler and it looks like the split method is the hottest spot.

[image]

EDIT 2: Simple example:

```
2,1 1:0.8 2:0.2
3   1:0.4 3:0.6
12  1:0.02 4:0.88 5:0.1
```

Expected output for class 2:

```
+1 1:0.8 2:0.2
-1 1:0.4 3:0.6
-1 1:0.02 4:0.88 5:0.1
```

Expected output for class 3:

```
-1 1:0.8 2:0.2
+1 1:0.4 3:0.6
-1 1:0.02 4:0.88 5:0.1
```

Expected output for class 4:

```
-1 1:0.8 2:0.2
-1 1:0.4 3:0.6
-1 1:0.02 4:0.88 5:0.1
```

Comment: "code below it takes 1 hour." but `Whole process took 00:00:00.1175102`? I'm confused.

Comment: I agree @tnw is a little bit strange there's something wrong

Comment: I think he runs on a larger set than 4 lines :)

Comment: Indeed, with 13*200 files of 64000 lines it took 1 hour

Comment: this is why you should be using proper LINQ (which can be easily parallelized) rather than horrible `for` loops from the stone age ;)

Comment: Try measureing how much of this time is I/O, and how much is actual processing time by generating the file in memory and writing it only after the loop.

Comment: @HighCore I thought it would be better to write on the disk sequentially. Writing 200 files in parallel was making my disk crazy.

Comment: You can very easily optimize out the GetClassTimes() method since it's really a static value. Just call it once at the beginning of the method and store it in a variable.

Comment: @itsme86 yep sure. I did it. I just got my example code wrong. I corrected the code

Comment: I'd also be worried about logical errors with your `lineFirstPart.Contains()`. e.g. Seeing if classValue of "40" is in the string "406,35" would show true, when it's really false. substring comparisons are notoriously CPU expensive anyway. I would personally split lineFirstPart again by ',' and turn that result into a HashSet<string>. then I'd see if hashSet.Contains(classValue) instead.

Comment: I made the correction with the hashset.

Comment: That's all I have. :) With the added comment that I would utilize Path.Combine() for generating the directory and file names.

Comment: Are the 200 class numbers contiguous -- values are 1 - 200?

Comment: @MikeHixson no they are not.

Comment: I found I can gain seconds by splitting the file lines before iterating over the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have eliminated the hottest paths from your code by removing the split and using a bigger buffer on the [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20d7x6t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Instead of Split I now call [ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then parse the first Chars to the first space and while I'm at it a match with classValue on a char by char basis is performed. The boolean `found` indicates an exact match for anything before the , of the first space. The rest of the handling is the same.

```
var fsw = new FileStream(classFilePath,
    FileMode.Create,
    FileAccess.Write,
    FileShare.None,
    64*1024*1024); // use a large buffer
using (var file = new StreamWriter(fsw)) // use the filestream
{
    foreach(var line in fileLines) // for( int i = 0;i < fileLines.Length;i++)
    {
        char[] chars = line.ToCharArray();
        int matched = 0;
        int parsePos = -1;
        bool takeClass = true;
        bool found = false;
        bool space = false;
        // parse until space
        while (parsePos<chars.Length && !space )
        {
            parsePos++;
            space = chars[parsePos] == ' '; // end
            // tokens
            if (chars[parsePos] == ' ' ||
                chars[parsePos] == ',')
            {
                if (takeClass 
                    && matched == classValue.Length)
                {
                    found = true;
                    takeClass = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // reset matching
                    takeClass = true;
                    matched = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (takeClass 
                    &&  matched < classValue.Length 
                    && chars[parsePos] == classValue[matched])
                {
                    matched++; // on the next iteration, match next
                }
                else
                {
                    takeClass = false; // no match!
                }    
            }
        }

        chars[parsePos - 1] = '1'; // replace 1 in front of space
        var correction = 1;
        if (parsePos > 1)
        {
            // is classValue before the comma (or before space)
            if (found)
            {
                chars[parsePos - 2] = '+';
            }
            else
            {
                chars[parsePos - 2] = '-';
            }
            correction++;
        }
        else
        {
            // is classValue before the comma (or before space)
            if (found)
            {
                // not enough space in the array, write a single char
                file.Write('+');
            }
            else
            {
                file.Write('-');
            }
        }
        file.WriteLine(chars, parsePos - correction, chars.Length - (parsePos - correction));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your version. It is very fast but does not do what's expected. For instance it identify a line with the label 12 as belonging the class 2. The +1 or -1 value is determined only by the first elements of the line which are comma separated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I added a simple example at the end of the question

Comment: I am sorry but it still does not produce the expected output.

Comment: I added a better parser that does some strict checking while still maintaining performance. Give it a try.

Comment: it works well for the simple case when there is only one class. But when there is two class on the same line such as 2,1 1:0.8 2:0.2 it only add the +1 on the file generated for class 2 but generate an incorrect file for class 1

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the parser bit. Based on your examples this works now

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the un-parsed lines 200 times, how about parsing the lines upfront into a data structure then iterating over that 200 times? This should minimize the numer of string manipulation operations.

Also using `StreamReader` instead of `File.ReadLines`, so the entire file is not in memory twice -- once as string[] and another time as Detail[].

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var details = ReadDetail("data.txt").ToArray();
    var classValues = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();

    foreach (var classValue in classValues)
    {
        // Create file/directory etc

        using (var file = new StreamWriter("out.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var detail in details)
            {
                file.WriteLine("{0} {1}", detail.Classes.Contains(classValue) ? "+1" : "-1", detail.Line);
            }
        }
    }
}

static IEnumerable<Detail> ReadDetail(string filePath)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            int separator = line.IndexOf(' ');

            Detail detail = new Detail
            {
                Classes = line.Substring(0, separator).Split(',').Select(c => Int32.Parse(c)).ToArray(),
                Line = line.Substring(separator + 1)
            };

            yield return detail;
        }
    }
}

public class Detail
{
    public int[] Classes { get; set; }
    public string Line { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My first approach was a lot like your code. It's a good idea but after testing it on a big file it does not really improve performances. Your code took 17.15 seconds while the one on this post took 17.43 seconds

Comment: You could probably squeeze out a bit more speed, by taking out the Int32.Parse() for the assignment in the Classes member. You'd have to specify `classValues` as a `IEnumerable<string>` as you have in your post.

Comment: Strike that. I just tried it, and its actually slower.